# Undefined symbols for architecture i386 with custom subclass

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm new in Xcode development and recently found some weird case during my project development, just wonder what if some one can help me on this, below is the error that I got when I tried to build/run:

```
Ld /Users/ACE/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ACE-ayqohtkcbgquxjgnnsbnwcketmir/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ACE.app/ACE normal i386
    cd /Users/ACE/Documents/Development/Products/ACE4
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/ACE/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ACE-ayqohtkcbgquxjgnnsbnwcketmir/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/ACE/Documents/Development/Products/ACE4/Classes/SUP/libs/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/ACE/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ACE-ayqohtkcbgquxjgnnsbnwcketmir/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist "/Users/ACE/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ACE-ayqohtkcbgquxjgnnsbnwcketmir/Build/Intermediates/ACE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ACE Simulator.build/Objects-normal/i386/ACE.LinkFileList" -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40200 -lz.1.2.5 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework AddressBook -framework CoreFoundation -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -lstdc++ -licucore.A -lclientrt -lMO -lSUPObj -framework MapKit -o /Users/ACE/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ACE-ayqohtkcbgquxjgnnsbnwcketmir/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ACE.app/ACE

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TransportMAPView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TransportViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

this error always appear when I tried to create an object using my custom class which is subclass from UIViewController

```
CustomViewController *customView = [[CustomViewController alloc] init];
```

and the weird thing is the error will gone and work perfectly if I use UIViewController directly

```
UIViewController *customView = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
```

below is the other error when I use custom class from UIButton:

```
Ld /Users/ACE/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ACE-ayqohtkcbgquxjgnnsbnwcketmir/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ACE.app/ACE normal i386
    cd /Users/ACE/Documents/Development/Products/ACE4
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/ACE/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ACE-ayqohtkcbgquxjgnnsbnwcketmir/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/ACE/Documents/Development/Products/ACE4/Classes/SUP/libs/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/ACE/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ACE-ayqohtkcbgquxjgnnsbnwcketmir/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist "/Users/ACE/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ACE-ayqohtkcbgquxjgnnsbnwcketmir/Build/Intermediates/ACE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ACE Simulator.build/Objects-normal/i386/ACE.LinkFileList" -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40200 -lz.1.2.5 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework AddressBook -framework CoreFoundation -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -lstdc++ -licucore.A -lclientrt -lMO -lSUPObj -framework MapKit -o /Users/ACE/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ACE-ayqohtkcbgquxjgnnsbnwcketmir/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ACE.app/ACE

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AceButton", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TransportViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

and this is my custom class:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AceButton : UIButton{
    NSString *identifier;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *identifier;

@end
```

in one of my View Controller method viewDidLoad()

```
AceButton *button1 = [[AceButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

Comment: I don't know what it is, but you should look at your CustomViewController. I would comment some things out and see if the error still appears. So you can slowly isolate the source of your error.

Answer (score 1):

The error message basically says that the class `TransportViewController` uses the class `TransportMAPView`, but the class `TransportMAPView` cannot be found by the linker (which towards the end of the build process combines all compiled code into a single executable).

Are the classes `TransportViewController` and `TransportMAPView` part of your code? If `TransportMAPView` is supposed to be in a libary, then the library wasn't properly added.

Comment: yes, I have created TransportMAPView in my library which is subclass from UIViewController and going to use this subclass in TransportViewController. but every time I used this custom class, it always throw me that error. this case not just happend to subclass of UIViewController, even UIButton and others also have same issue.

Comment: I don't understand where your classes are. Do you have a single projects with the iPhone app, or do you have the app and an additional library (from a separate XCode project)? And please add some of the other error messages to your question. If they relate to UIButton, then they likely have a different cause.

Comment: Hi Codo thank you for your reply, I have only one project for my app and to make it simple let's say I create a project and within this project I have created few subclass like UIViewController, UITableViewController. all of this subclass can be used previously, and suddenly the problem rise and I can't create any object using custom class anymore. I have added new error within original question.

Comment: It seems that the files `TransportMAPView.m` and `AceButton.m` aren't part your XCode project anymore or have been assigned an invalid file type. Please post the contents of `/Users/ACE/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ACE-ayqohtkcbgquxjgnnsbnwcketmir/Build/Intermediates/ACE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ACE Simulator.build/Objects-normal/i386/ACE.LinkFileList` to verify it.

Comment: Thank you for you reply, I have checked the file that you mentioned and can't find AceButton.m in that list. Do you have any idea how to solve this matter? for your information, the TransportMAPView now working properly, it's happend since I remove/delete it from project folder and then create a new one with same name, but not when I do the same approach with AceButton.(checked the file and TransportMAPView is already there)